# Can't install an application on device via iPhone Configuration Utility

Tags: iphone, ios

Something's changed recently with iPhone Configuration Utility, and I can't install an application on the device. It used to work well, but everything's changed (I suppose) after I updated iTunes to 11.0.2 and iPhone to 6.1.2.

The symptoms are:

- Every time I start iTunes I got "Unknown error (-42110)" message.
- iPhone Configuration Utility often lags and freezes.
- iPhone Configuration Utility shows error "Could not transfer application to device. Error: kAMDUndefinedEror."

Any ideas how to solve it?

PS: Mac mini, Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit

UPD: Fixed iTunes "Unknown error (-42110)" issue by removing C:\ProgramData\Apple Computer\iTunes\SC Info folder. But iPhone Configuration Utility still can't install an application.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh.. you have updated your device to 6.1.2 so i think you need a Mountain Lion OS for MAC. since it is not able to work with lion 10.7.5 also. Update your system to mountain lion. it will be fine again.

Comment: Well... I don't know how it's connected... I've got Mountain Lion on Mac partition (though not with the latest update) but my issue is under Windows 7.